# Inject matchesJsonPath from Groovy into Spring Cloud Contract

Tags: groovy, spring-cloud-contract

When writing a Spring Cloud Contract in Groovy,
I want to specify an explicit JSON path expression.
The expression:

```
"$.['variants'][*][?(@.['name'] == 'product_0004' && @.['selected'] == true)]"
```

shall appear in the generated `json`, like so:

```
{
  "request" : {
    "bodyPatterns": [ {
      "matchesJsonPath": "$.['variants'][*][?(@.['name'] == 'product_0004' && @.['selected'] == true)]"
    } ]
  }
}
```

in order to match e.g.:

```
{ "variants": [
    { "name": "product_0003", "selected": false },
    { "name": "product_0004", "selected": true  },
    { "name": "product_0005", "selected": false } ]
}
```

and to *not* match e.g.:

```
{ "variants": [
    { "name": "product_0003", "selected": false },
    { "name": "product_0004", "selected": false },
    { "name": "product_0005", "selected": true  } ]
}
```

Is this possible using consumers, bodyMatchers, or some other facility of the Groovy DSL?

Answer (score 0):

There are some possibilities with matching on json path, but you wouldn't necessarily use it for matching on explicit values, but rather to make a flexible stub for the consumer by using regex. There are some possibilities though.

So the body section is your static request body with hardcoded values, while the bodyMatchers section provides you the ability to make the stub matching from the consumer side more flexible.

```
Contract.make {
  request {
    method 'POST'
    url '/some-url'
    body ([
      id: id
      items: [
         foo: foo
         bar: bar
      ],
      [
         foo: foo
         bar: foo
      ]
    ])
    bodyMatchers {
        jsonPath('$.id', byEquality())       //1
        jsonPath('$.items[*].foo', byRegex('(?:^|\\W)foo(?:$|\\W)'))    //2
        jsonPath('$.items[*].bar', byRegex(nonBlank()))     //3
      }
      headers {
          contentType(applicationJson())
      }
  }
  response {
    status 200
  }
}
```

I referenced some lines

1: "byEquality()" in the bodyMatchers section means: the input from the consumer must be equal to the value provided in the body for this contract/stub to match, in other words must be "id".

2: I'm not sure how nicely the //1 solution will work when the property is in a list, and you want the stub to be flexible with the amount of items provided. Therefor I also included this byRegex which basically means, for any item in the list, the property foo must have exactly value "foo". However, I dont really know why you would want to do this.

3: This is where bodyMatchers are actually most useful. This line means: match to this contract if every property bar in the list of items is a non blank string. This allows you to have a dynamic stub with a flexible size of lists/arrays.

All the conditions in bodyMatchers need to be met for the stub to match.

Comment: The `items[*]` selector selects a different item in every bodyMatchers clause. I need it to be the same clause. Added an example for clarification.